# 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to build a telegram bot, I have the requirements but when I wrote the code and ran it, it gave me a error of AttributeError

```py
File "\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    disp = updater.dispatcher
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'
```

I researched a bit but found nothing this is my whole code:

```py
import telegram.ext as ext

with open('D:/NeuralNine/Telegram bot/TOKEN.txt', 'r') as f:
    TOKEN = f.read().strip()

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Hello! Welcome to the bot!')

def help(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('You can use the following commands:')
    update.message.reply_text('/start - Welcome message')
    update.message.reply_text('/help - show this message')
    update.message.reply_text('/about - show the author')



def about(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Author')

updater = ext.Updater(TOKEN, True)
disp = updater.dispatcher

disp.add_handler(ext.CommandHandler('start', start))
disp.add_handler(ext.CommandHandler('help', help))
disp.add_handler(ext.CommandHandler('about', about))

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

I'm using the version 20.7 for python-telegram-bot
Is there any way to fix it?

I even tried it without the dispatcher, I thought it was worth a try, but nothing happened.